# User Cart Data Not Persisting Across Logins in Django E-commerce Project

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce, cart

I am developing an e-commerce project using Django, and I have encountered an issue with persisting user cart data across login sessions. When a user logs in and adds products to their cart, the cart items are not visible when the user logs in again at a later time.

*cart view*

```
def cart_details(request,tot=0,count=0,cart_items=None,ct_items=None):
    try:
        ct=cartlist.objects.get(cart_id=c_id(request))
        ct_items=items.objects.filter(cart=ct,active=True)
        for i in ct_items:
            tot += (i.prod.price*i.quan)
            count += i.quan

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("<script> alert('Empty Cart');window.location='/';</script>")

    return render(request,'cart.html',{'ci':ct_items,'t':tot,'cn':count})

def c_id(request):
    ct_id=request.session.session_key
    if not ct_id:
        ct_id=request.session.create()
    return ct_id

def add_cart(request,product_id):
    prod=products.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        ct=cartlist.objects.get(cart_id=c_id(request))
    except cartlist.DoesNotExist:
        ct=cartlist.objects.create(cart_id=c_id(request))
        ct.save()

    try:
        c_items=items.objects.get(prod=prod,cart=ct)
        if c_items.quan < c_items.prod.stock:
            c_items.quan+=1
        c_items.save()
    except items.DoesNotExist:
        c_items=items.objects.create(prod=prod,quan=1,cart=ct)
        c_items.save()
    return redirect('cartDetails')

def min_cart(request,product_id):
    ct=cartlist.objects.get(cart_id=c_id(request))
    prod=get_object_or_404(products,id=product_id)
    c_items=items.objects.get(prod=prod,cart=ct)
    if c_items.quan>1:
        c_items.quan-=1
        c_items.save()
    else:
        c_items.delete()
    return redirect('cartDetails')
def cart_delete(request,product_id):
    ct=cartlist.objects.get(cart_id=c_id(request))
    prod=get_object_or_404(products,id=product_id)
    c_items=items.objects.get(prod=prod,cart=ct)
    c_items.delete()
    return redirect('cartDetails')
```

**cart models**

```
class cartlist(models.Model):
    cart_id=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id


class items(models.Model):

    prod=models.ForeignKey(products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)    #here class/tale product from shop is act as a foreign key so we can fetch the values ...
    cart=models.ForeignKey(cartlist,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quan=models.IntegerField()
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prod)
```

**login**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        if password1 == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "username is already taken")
                return redirect("register")

            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, "email is already taken")
                return redirect("register")

            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email,first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                user.save()
                print("user created")
        else:
            print("password not correct")
            return redirect('register')

        return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')


def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid details')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Implemented user authentication in Django to handle user logins.
2. Created the shopping cart functionality, allowing users to add products to their cart.
3. During a single session, the cart works correctly and displays the added items.

However, when the user logs out and logs back in again, the previously added items are not retained in the cart. It appears that the cart data is not persisting across login sessions.

I am using Django's default authentication system and have not made any modifications to it.

How to address this issue? What steps should I take to ensure that the user's cart data is saved and retrieved correctly across login sessions in Django? Are there any specific Django features or techniques that I should consider?

nb:i know cart models is not store any information about user , i try it but it ended with some error